# Smooth scrolling to next div

Tags: jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I'm currently using the smooth scrolling technique to scroll from div to div, basically I have a whole load of divs, one after the other, when you click on the current div it takes you to the next one etc.
But that's where I'm having a problem, as currently I have to set the # for each div to tell it to go to the next. Here's my code, it might make a bit more sense:
HTML:

```
        <a href="#slide-2"><div id="slide-1" class="slides">
            <div class="text">
ONE
            </div>
        </div></a>

         <a href="#slide-3"><div id="slide-2" class="slides">
            <div class="text">
TWO 
            </div>
        </div></a>  

        <a href="#slide-4"><div id="slide-3" class="slides">
            <div class="text">
THREE
            </div>
        </div></a>  

        <a href="#slide-5"><div id="slide-4" class="slides">
            <div class="text">
FOUR
            </div>
        </div></a>  

        <a href="#slide-6"><div id="slide-5" class="slides">
            <div class="text">
FIVE
            </div>
        </div></a>  

        <a href="#slide-7"><div id="slide-6" class="slides">
            <div class="text">
SIX
            </div>
        </div></a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the "normal" behaviour which would be a "hard" jump

    var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target

    // perform animated scrolling by getting top-position of target-element and set it as scroll target
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top }, 400, function() {
         location.hash = target;  //attach the hash (#jumptarget) to the pageurl
    });

    return false;
   });
});
```

As you can see, the href for slide-1 takes you to slide-2, and so on, but there will be quite a lot of divs in the end, with more being added as and when, so I was wondering if there was a simpler way of scrolling from div to div, i.e. Is there a way of detecting the next div and scrolling to it and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add classes to the `a` elements and use `next` and `find` methods.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.className').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      var offset = $(this).next().find('div').offset().top;
      $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 400);
   });
});
```

You can also select the elements and cache the objects:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $a = $('a.className'), $targets = $('div.targets');
   $a.on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
      var i = $a.index(this);
      var offset = $targets.eq(++i).offset().top;
      $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: offset }, 400);
   });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the index of your div and slide to the next.

```
$(".linkToNextDiv").click(function(e)
{
    var parent = $(this).parent("div");
    var index = $(parent).index();
    scrollToDiv(index+1);
});
```

This is just a generic example. You'll need to adapt it to your code.